# C# datagridview Columns clear on sort

Tags: c#, datagridview, issue-tracking, gridview-sorting

```
        var ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(XMLFile);

        DataGridLogView.DataSource = ds.Tables["Header"];
        DataGridLogView.DataMember = "Data";
        DataGridLogView.Columns.Add("5", "Record #");
        DataGridLogView.Columns.Add("6", "Record");
```

The columns "5" & "6" are the problem columns that i add after my datasource loads in. I can sort any column besides the two i created(5 & 6) but when i sort any of the columns, the two columns i create will clear of all data i add and i cannot seem to figure out why it is doing this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is data getting input into the two columns that are not part of the 'DataTable'?

Comment: @JohnG I load it in from a text file.

Comment: What dictates which row in the grid belongs to which text data? Have you considered adding the columns to the `DataTable` AFTER the first data has been read in? When you add columns to a grid that already has a data source, YOU will have to manage those columns. I would try adding the columns to the data table and see if this helps. I am confident this will keep the items in place when sorting; however, I am not so sure if the performance will improve.

Comment: @JohnG I am loading in my XML file first to the data grid because my text file is matching record numbers in the text file to record numbers in the XML file to know which line is going where. In its current state performance is no issue but with this sorting thing clearing my rows it is making my program much less helpful.

Comment: As I stated in my last comment, using one `DataTable` for this will solve the sorting problem. You do not state HOW the second read of the text file is accomplished and the data added to the grid. If you are using a loop to read the second data, then (as I recommended earlier), add the two extra columns to the `DataTable` not the grid… then as you loop/read the text data, put the values in the appropriate rows in the `DataTable`. Idea being, you add the data to the `DataTable` not the grid, then the sorting should work as expected.

Comment: @JohnG maybe I do not know how to correctly add my text columns to the same datatable correctly then. I will research a little more of this

Comment: Have you tried to create a new `DataTable` for this? Example: `DataTable gridDataTable = YourTableFromTheDataSet; gridDataTable.Columns.Add(“Record #”, typeOf(string)); etc`…then you should be able to add the text data to the added columns. And lastly set the grid’s data source to `gridDataTable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       datatable.Columns.Add("Record #", typeof(string));
       datatable.Columns.Add("Record", typeof(string));
```

I had to add the columns to the dataset before setting the datagridviews datasource then the sorting worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

With a DataGridView control bound to an external data source, non-data bound cells are not automatically persisted when sorting. Your added columns are not in the dataset, so they get cleared. If your columns "5" and "6" are derived from the row data you might try filling them in the DataGridView.RowsAdded event. Alternatively you could reload those columns in the DataGridView.Sorted event.

Comment: I think that answer is great but my only problem is that i am using larger files consisting of 50k -100k lines long and load in two columns from the file, that being said reloading those on every sort seems to cause performance issues.